# Update state with Object using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state, use-state

I'm getting data from `Firebase` and want to update `state`:

```
const [allProfile, setAllProfile] = useState([]);
.....
const displayProfileList = async () => {
        try {

            await profile
                .get()
                .then(querySnapshot => {

                    querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                        const documentId = doc.id;                        
                        const nProfile = { id: documentId, doc: doc.data()}                        
                        console.log(nProfile);//nProfile contains data
                    
                        setAllProfile([...allProfile, nProfile]);
                        console.log(allProfile); // is empty
                    }
                    );

                })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('xxx', error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: State is updated asynchronously. State and props are constant within a particular render of a component. To see the updated state, component has to re-render. Use `useEffect` hook to log the updated state value.

Comment: Not related to your problem but you shouldn't mix `async-await` syntax with `promise-chaining`. Use either one of them, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setAllProfile` will update the state when the iteration is done. So in order for your code to work, you will need to pass the callback function to the `setAllProfile` as shown in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

```
setAllProfile((prevState) => [...prevState, nProfile])
```

**UPDATE**

[Example demonstrating this at work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3k2ylr?file=src/App.js)

Comment: i noticed that he did set state inside map, but his original question was not about this. his issue was console log update.

Answer (score 2):

Since `setAllProfile` is the asynchronous method, you can't get the updated value immediately after `setAllProfile`. You should get it inside `useEffect` with adding a `allProfile` dependency.

```
setAllProfile([...allProfile, nProfile]);
console.log(allProfile); // Old `allProfile` value will be printed, which is the initial empty array.
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(allProfile);
}, [allProfile]);
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
const [allProfile, setAllProfile] = useState([]);
.....
const displayProfileList = async () => {
        try {

            await profile
                .get()
                .then(querySnapshot => {
                    const profiles = [];

                    querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                        const documentId = doc.id;                        
                        const nProfile = { id: documentId, doc: doc.data()}                        
                        console.log(nProfile);//nProfile contains data
                        profiles.push(nProfile);
                    
                    }
                    );
                    setAllProfile([...allProfile, ...profiles]);


                })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('xxx', error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: => when on `return` I trying to display data, then it's showing me last element :/ `{allProfile.map(profile => (
 <tr key={profile.id}>
  <td>{profile.id} </td>
    </tr>
))}`

Comment: yes, you can see the updated `allProfile` in the render. that's because as soon as state is updated, render is re-rendered.

Comment: what i meant is what you have done to setAllProfile is correct, but just wrong to check the updated value. you just need to check the updated state value inside useEffect.

Comment: I did as you wrote but I see just one element, answer @k.s. is working

Comment: This answer is a valid answer and should work. I think the problem OP is referring to is because of the closure of the callback function of over the state which is fixed by using the previous state..

Comment: @WilliamWang - as I wrote, when I tried into `return` display data, it's display just one record (last one)

Comment: oh, i've never noticed that you are trying to set state inside array.map. i have updated the answer. it would be better to set state once outside of array.map.

Comment: @4est your original question was about the logging of old value of state and this answer answers your question. The problem you are describing is because of the closure that gets fixed when using the previous state.

Comment: @WilliamWang - thanks, I have tested your answer now and it's working as well

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `setState` inside a `map` and therefore create few async calls, all referred to by current `..allProfile` value call (and not `prev => [...prev`...)

Try

```
 let arr=[]
 querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                  arr.push({ id: doc.id, doc: doc.data() })
            }                                 
 setAllProfile(prev=>[...prev,  ...arr])
```

I don't sure how the architecture of fetching the posts implemented (in terms of pagination and so on, so you might don't need to destruct `...prev`

Comment: - answer from k.s. is working as expected